# Is using menuItem.getItemId() valid in finding which MenuItem is selected by user?

Tags: android

I have menu in my App. I need to check for the which menu item been selected by the user and take appropriate action. I did this as,

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuitem){
        String title = menuitem.getTitle().toString();
        int itemId = menuitem.getItemId();
                    switch(itemId){
                        case 2131296257:
                                -----------------;
                                break;
                        case 2131296258:
                                 ------------------;
                                 break;                             
                    }
```

But these MenuItem Id's are getting changed each time I run my App. Now I thought to compare the menuTitle with hard coded string values like ,

```
 String title = menuitem.getTitle().toString();

   if(title.equals("Settings..")){
                ------------- 
                ------------- 
                -------------
   }
```

But I don't think it's a good practice. But I guess I can do the same using the menu titles defined in strings.xml. But I am not sure how to use this.... (like R.string.....).

Can someone suggest on this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Here's an example menu named game_menu.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

**Inflating a Menu Resource**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**Responding to user action**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

for more information [click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: oh... I missed that basic thing...very bad... :-)  Thanks